# How to Predict the future values of time horizon with keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, forecasting

i buid this model with **LSTM Neural network** on keras using a daily demand data

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd 
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
    from keras.activations import linear
    from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from matplotlib import pyplot

    #read and prepare data from datafile
    data_file_name = "DailyDemand.csv"
    data_csv = pd.read_csv(data_file_name, delimiter = ';',header=None, usecols=[1,2,3,4,5])
    yt = data_csv[1:]
    data = yt
    data.columns = ['MoyenneTransactHier', 'MaxTransaction', 'MinTransaction','CountTransaction','Demand']
    # print (data.head(10))
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
    data = data.dropna ()
    y=data['Demand'].astype(int)
    cols=['MoyenneTransactHier', 'MaxTransaction', 'MinTransaction','CountTransaction']
    x=data[cols].astype(int)

    #scaling data
    scaler_x = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(-1, 1))
    x = np.array(x).reshape ((len(x),4 ))
    x = scaler_x.fit_transform(x)
    scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(-1, 1))
    y = np.array(y).reshape ((len(y), 1))
    y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)
    print("longeur de y",len(y))
    # Split train and test data
    train_end = 400
    x_train=x[0: train_end ,]
    x_test=x[train_end +1: ,]
    y_train=y[0: train_end]
    y_test=y[train_end +1:] 
    x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape +(1,))
    x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

    print("Data well prepared")
    print ('x_train shape ', x_train.shape)
    print ('y_train', y_train.shape)

    #Design the model - LSTM Network
    seed = 2016
    np.random.seed(seed)
    fit1 = Sequential ()
    fit1.add(LSTM(
        output_dim = 4,
        activation='tanh',
        input_shape =(4, 1)))
    fit1.add(Dense(output_dim =1))
    fit1.add(Activation(linear))
    #rmsprop or sgd
    batchsize = 1
    fit1.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="rmsprop")
    #train the model
    fit1.fit(x_train , y_train , batch_size = batchsize, nb_epoch =20, shuffle=True)

    print(fit1.summary ())

    #Model error
    score_train = fit1.evaluate(x_train ,y_train ,batch_size =batchsize)
    score_test = fit1.evaluate(x_test , y_test ,batch_size =batchsize)
    print("in  train  MSE = ",round(score_train,4))
    print("in test  MSE = ",round(score_test ,4))

    #Make prediction
    pred1=fit1.predict(x_test)
    pred1 = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(pred1).reshape ((len(pred1), 1)))
    real_test = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(y_test).reshape ((len(y_test), 1))).astype(int)

    #save prediction
    testData = pd.DataFrame(real_test)
    preddData = pd.DataFrame(pred1)
    dataF = pd.concat([testData,preddData], axis=1)
    dataF.columns =['Real demand','Predicted Demand']
    dataF.to_csv('Demandprediction.csv')

    pyplot.plot(pred1, label='Forecast')
    pyplot.plot(real_test,label='Actual')
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.show()
```

And it generates this result:
[image: Prediction on the test data]

After buiding and training a good model on the history data that i have, i dont know how i can gererates the prediction of the future values? for example the demand of the next 10 days (Data are daily) ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to predict 10 days of data for instance, you will need 10 outputs in the last layer

```
fit1.add(Dense(10))
```

You will need to train the model accordingly, with preferred inputs and outputs from the historic data. For example if you want a model that takes in 10 days of data and predicts data for 10 days in the future, then you will have to train the model by respective  input-output pairs of 10 from the historic data